# Difference between two DataFrames based on only one column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking for a way to find the difference of two DataFrames based on one column. For example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

df_a = sql_context.createDataFrame([("fa", 3), ("fb", 5), ("fc", 7)], ["first name", "id"])

df_b = sql_context.createDataFrame([("la", 3), ("lb", 10), ("lc", 13)], ["last name", "id"])
DataFrame A:

+----------+---+
|first name| id|
+----------+---+
|        fa|  3|
|        fb|  5|
|        fc|  7|
+----------+---+
DataFrame B:

+---------+---+
|last name| id|
+---------+---+
|       la|  3|
|       lb| 10|
|       lc| 13|
+---------+---+
```

My goal is to find the difference of DataFrame A and DataFrame B considering column id, the output would be the following DataFrame

```
    +---------+---+
    |last name| id|
    +---------+---+
    |       lb| 10|
    |       lc| 13|
    +---------+---+
```

I don't want to use the following method:

```
a_ids = set(df_a.rdd.map(lambda r: r.id).collect())
df_c = df_b.filter(~col('id').isin(a_ids))
```

I'm looking for an efficient method (in terms of memory and speed) that I don't have to collect the ids (the size of ids can be billions), maybe something like RDDs SubtractByKey but for DataFrame

PS: I can map df_a to RDD, but I don't want to map df_b to RDD

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `left_anti` join on column `id`:

```
df_b.join(df_a.select('id'), how='left_anti', on=['id']).show()
+---+---------+
| id|last name|
+---+---------+
| 10|       lb|
| 13|       lc|
+---+---------+
```